# Center in the group of affine maps

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ denote the set of maps $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ which have the form $f(x) = ax + b$ for $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ where $a \neq 0$. Under composition, this is a group. I'm trying to find its center.

My hunch from trying some examples is that it has a trivial center.

Given an element $f$ as above, I'm going to try to find an element of $G$ that doesn't commute with it. Let $g$ be the element defined by $g(x) = cx + d$ for $c \neq 0$. Then
\begin{align*}
(f \circ g)(x) &= f(cx + d) = a(cx + d) + b = acx + ad + b \\
(g \circ f)(x) &= g(ax + b) = c(ax + b) + d = acx + bc + d. 
\end{align*}
So I need to pick $c$ and $d$ so that $ad + b \neq bc + d$. I don't know if there's a closed-form expression for such a $g$, but the fact that I found a condition on $g$ that makes this equality false implies that I can find an element of $G$ that doesn't commute with $f$.

I'd appreciate some help with understanding this.

Comment: The [tag:proof-explanation] tag is for when you have a particular proof you want an explanation of.

Answer (score 1):

The center is indeed trivial.  Suppose your $f(x) = ax+b$ commutes with **everything**.  Then it commutes with $g(x) = x+1$, and using your identities with $c=1$ and $d=1$ this gives $a+b=b+1$ for the constant terms, so $a=1$.  Hence $f(x) = x+b$.  Now play around similarly to get $b=0$.  Thus $f(x)=x$ is the only element in the center, and this is of course your identity element.

Note that you have to play around with the constant terms of $f \circ g$ and $g \circ f$, since the degree 1 coefficients are always going to agree.  The only hope for information will come from the constant terms.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to think about this geometrically. $G$ is generated by scaling

$$s_a : x \mapsto ax$$

and by translation

$$t_b : x \mapsto x + b.$$

An element $g \in G$ is in the center iff it commutes with scaling and with translation. It will turn out to be conceptually nicer to think about this in terms of conjugation: $g$ is central iff conjugation by scaling and by translation reproduces $g$, meaning that

$$s_a g s_a^{-1} = t_b g t_b^{-1} = g.$$

The point of rewriting things in this way is that we can give a conceptual interpretation of these conjugations, as follows. Every element $x \mapsto ax + b$ of $G$ is either a translation ($a = 1$) or, if $a \neq 1$, has a unique fixed point acting on $\mathbb{R}$, namely the unique solution to $x_f = ax_f + b$, given by $x_f = \frac{b}{1 - a}$, and acts as scaling by $a$ around this unique fixed point. Now, check that

1. conjugation by a scaling $s_c$ a) acts on a translation to scale the translation vector by $c$, and b) acts on a scaling to scale the fixed point by $c$ but leave the scale factor unaffected, and
2. conjugation by a translation $t_d$ a) leaves translations unaffected, and b) acts on a scaling to translate the fixed point by $d$ but leave the scale factor unaffected.

It follows that if $g \in G$ commutes with all scalings then it must be a scaling around the origin, but then it can't commute with all scalings unless it's the identity.

This may seem like a lot of work but this style of argument generalizes cleanly to understanding the behavior of the [affine group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_group) in higher dimensions. And note that we've proven something stronger than what was desired: this actually characterizes all conjugacy classes of the affine group, namely 1) the identity, 2) nontrivial translations (which are all conjugate), and 3) scalings by each nontrivial scale factor (which are all conjugate for each scale factor $a \neq 1$).